# Windows 10 Search Instant Calculator Not Working

Tags: windows-10, search, windows-search, calculator

Usually, typing a few numbers with an operator into Windows 10 Search
would give an instant calculation, but this doesn't work on my laptop.

[image]

I don't remember when it stopped working. I have the Creator's Update but I'm not sure that's what broke it. Any help would be greatly appreciated as this problem is incredibly inconvenient.

Comment: Start > Run > Winver.exe > which build? It's working for me in  build10240 on Enterprise edition.

Comment: OS Build 15063.674

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I disabled Cortana at some point and forgot about it. I fixed the problem by downloading and running Winaero Tweaker and unchecking "Disable Cortana."

Answer (score 0):

It should not be a version related issue, on my 15063.674 Enterprise computer, calculation is normal.

[image]

You need to ensure Cortana is turned on and computer is connecting to Internet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a 2004ver 19041.264build of windows. And recently I noticed this issue after switching region from "United States" in Settings > Time&Language > Region > Country or region. After bringing US back calculations work again.